# Why does attempting to fetch an object url with UrlFetchApp result in an Error 400?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am attempting to write a Google App Script that has a user upload an an image to my google drive. However, when I create an object url for the image, URLFetchApp fails at requesting it. Here's the Google script side of things:

```js
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function uploadFile(objurl) {
 var n=objurl.slice(5);
  Logger.log(n);
  var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(n).getBlob();
  var file = {
    title: 'google_logo.png',
    mimeType: 'image/png'
  };
  file = Drive.Files.insert(file, image);
  Logger.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', file.id, file.fileSize);
}
```

...and here's the javascript/HTML side of things...

```html
<form>
Photo: <input type="file" name="photo" id="p" accept="image/png, image/jpeg"><br>
<input type="button" onClick="formSubmit()" value="Add">
</form>
<script>
function formSubmit() {
var pic = document.getElementById("p")
var blob = new Blob([pic], { type: 'application/javascript' });
var objurl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
google.script.run.uploadFile(objurl);
}
</script>
```

I am brand new to, well, all of the above, and would greatly appreciate help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### An object URL is only valid during the browser session and cannot be used to pass a file to Drive.

Instead, you need a data URL, a useful method is [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Here is how you can modify your code to make it work:

> HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  Photo: <input type="file" name="photo" id="p" accept="image/png, image/jpeg"><br>
  <input type="button" onClick="formSubmit()" value="Add"><br>
  <script>
   function formSubmit(){
       var file    = document.getElementById("p").files[0]; 
      //  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; 
       var reader  = new FileReader();
       if (file) {
           //console.log(reader);
           reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
           reader.onloadend = function () {
           google.script.run.uploadFile(reader.result);
          }           
       }                      
  }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Script file

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}    
function uploadFile(image) {
   try {
     var mimeType = image.substring(5,image.indexOf(';'));
     bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(image.substr(image.indexOf('base64,')+7));
     var title='google_logo.png';
     blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, mimeType, title);
     file=DriveApp.createFile(blob);
     Logger.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', file.getId(), file.getSize());
     return "OK";
  } catch (f) {
    return f.toString();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know if it's possible to add an uploaded file to a specific Drive folder?

Comment: Sure: DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").createFile(blob);